# JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing in C#

Tags: c#, json, jwt, token

So I am trying to decode my jwt token. I've just recently added a new object to it called "userGroupList". This is basically a class that gets converted to a string with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`. Problem is that when I try to decode my jwt token now I get this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'userGroupList', line 1,

This is how the jwt token gets created:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Logics.GetJwtToken(new JwtModel { UserId = user.UserId, UserName = user.UserName, Rank = user.Rank, UserGroupList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user.UserGroups)}));
```

This is the code:

```
public static JwtModel ValidateJwtTokenWithResult(string token)
{
    try
    {
        string[] parts = token.Split('.');
        string payload = parts[0] + "." + parts[1];
        string hash = parts[2];
        if (ConfirmToken(payload, hash, "secretthing"))
        {
            JwtModel basejwt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JwtModel>(Base64UrlEncoder.Decode(parts[1]));
            return basejwt;
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class JwtModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Rank { get; set; }
    public string UserGroupList { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the token I am trying to deserialize:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI0IiwidXNlck5hbWUiOiJSYXltb25kIEZ1bmciLCJyYW5rIjoiTWFuYWdlciIsInVzZXJHcm91cExpc3QiOlt7IklkIjoxLCJOYW1lIjoiQ29udGFjdHMifSx7IklkIjoyLCJOYW1lIjoiRnVuZHMifSx7IklkIjozLCJOYW1lIjoiQ29tcGxpYW5jZSJ9XX0.Aq6UQJkBslh10Fxkr8MZjuxgqHZxmpWv295kqpG8wo8=

Which translates to:

```
{
    "userId": "2",
    "userName": "John Smith",
    "rank": "Manager",
    "userGroupList": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Contacts"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Funds"
        },
        {
            "Id": 3,
            "Name": "Compliance"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am still fairly new to C#. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change the type of `UserGroupList` in your `JwtModel` to `List<UserGroup>` (or whatever the type is called) this should do the trick.

Comment: json like `[...]` is not a string ... it's an array ... I'm pretty sure that it takes less than 20 sec to: find json to C# code tool online and use it to generate model class

Comment: Hey Croxy. I changed the type to IEnumerable<UserGroup> UserGroupList and removed the JsonConvert.SerializeObject. After this it seems to be working. Thank you!

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io?share=CLyWwqUUuDuZarVkkr3o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
public string UserGroupList { get; set; }
```

to

```
public IList<UserGroup> UserGroupList { get; set; }
```

then create class for `UserGroup`

```
class UserGroup {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

also `UserId` looks like string rather than int

```
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

to

```
public string UserId { get; set; }
```

Comment: I did this and also removed JsonConvert.SerializeObject and it seems to be working. Thank you for your help!